# The length of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with a Linear Algebra problem that involves finding the length of a vector

$w_1 = (i, 1, 0) \in W$ a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$

So, the way I did it is like this:

$$\|w_1\| = \sqrt{i^2 + 1^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt{-1 + 1 + 0} = 0$$

Is this correct?

Comment: That's a really short vector. You might want to check the definition of length in the complex case.

Comment: BTW, $W$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.  You could say $W$ _is_ $\mathbb{C}^3$, and $\mathbb{C}^3$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for that. What's the LaTEX for the complex symbol? ... Nevermind, I copied it from the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of a vector $v=(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n$ is $||v||=\sqrt{z_1\overline{z_1}+\ldots + z_n\overline{z_n}}$, where $\overline z$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z$.

Comment: Ooooh! I seeeee! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You have to multiply each component not by itself, but by its complex conjugate.  A component is real if and only if it is its own complex conjugate, so you multiply $0$ by $0$, getting $0^2$, and $1$ by $1$, getting $1^2$.  But $i$ is not real.  Its complex conjugate is $-i$.